# After doing groupingBy, i want to get the Top2 from each group, How i can get this in Java 8

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

```
Map<Object, List<MasterView>> result = 
    navList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(navData-> 
    new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(navData.getCode(),navData.getCurrency()))));
```

From this I am getting the group.

How to proceed after that ?

Comment: TopN implies ordering so you should provide some Comparator

Comment: The method `Arrays.asList` does already return a `List`. There is no sense in copying it into an `ArrayList` via `new ArrayList<String>(…)`. Besides that, it’s impossible to tell you how to select the “top two” without knowing your metric. How are we supposed to know what makes a `MasterView` the top one of a list of them?

Answer (score 1):

You can add *collectingAndThen* as second argument to your groupingBy that will perform your additional finishing transformation to the final list.

```
Collector<MasterView, Object, List<MasterView>> top2 = Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), it -> it.stream().limit(2).collect(Collectors.toList()));
        
Map<Object, List<MasterView>> result =
                navList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(navData->
                        new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(navData.getCode(),navData.getCurrency())), top2));
```

See if this helps you.

Comment: You are not collecting the “top two” but the “first two”. It’s not clear whether the OP wants that, as the question doesn’t tell what makes two elements the “top two”. But when you want to collect the first two, it’s more efficient to use a custom collector that simply stops after collecting two elements, instead of collecting all elements into a list, to perform another stream operation to get the first two.

Answer (score 0):

List navList = new ArrayList<>();

```
navList.add(new MasterView(195, 21));
navList.add(new MasterView(115, 30));
navList.add(new MasterView(115, 34));
navList.add(new MasterView(145, 58));
navList.add(new MasterView(145, 28));
navList.add(new MasterView(155, 26));
navList.add(new MasterView(155, 27));
navList.add(new MasterView(177, 22));
navList.add(new MasterView(177, 20));
navList.add(new MasterView(177, 10));
navList.add(new MasterView(177, 12));

Map<Integer, List<MasterView>> result =
        navList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(MasterView::getCode));

Map<Integer, List<MasterView>> top2Map = new HashMap<>();
for (Map.Entry<Integer, List<MasterView>> entry : result.entrySet()) {
    List<MasterView> masterViews = entry.getValue();
    if (masterViews.size() > 2)
        masterViews.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());
    else if (masterViews.size() == 1)
        top2Map.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().get(0)));
    else
        top2Map.put(entry.getKey(), Arrays.asList(entry.getValue().get(0), entry.getValue().get(1)));
}
```

If you want to use the method Collections.sort() with a custom object you need to prepare it:

```
class MasterView implements Comparable<MasterView> {
    private Integer code;
    private Integer currency;

    public MasterView(int code, int currency) {
        this.code = code;
        this.currency = currency;
    }

    public Integer getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(Integer code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public Integer getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }

    public void setCurrency(Integer currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }


    @Override
    public int compareTo(MasterView o) {
        return this.getCurrency().compareTo(o.getCurrency());
    }
}
```